# Has the OEM messed up?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tablet

I recently acquired a new Alldaymall A88S tablet running on Android 4.4.2 KitKat
It appears to be a stock recovery, stock ROM. It was not new, but it was untouched.However, when I booted it, and peeked into the settings, I found some bizarre things:

- I can record the screen **without root** (Never mind. I have root, the screen decoder is built-in)
- Developer options was already unlocked, with *USB debugging* and *allow mock locations* already ticked.
- I have access to mobile data options- yet I have no SIM, and nothing to suggest I should have These options exist
- Most bizarrely, I have the ability to change the runtime between Dalvik and ART freely, from the developer options.

Has the OEM really failed/deviated from the norm, or has the previous owner tweaked it?

Comment: "It was not new, but it was untouched"... What exactly does this mean? But more to your point, it would be EXTREMELY unlikely the OEM has USB Debugging enabled by default. I would use a root checker app to see if it's rooted, then factory default it and see if developer options disappears.

Comment: @acejavelin ah, well, there's an issue. It has Root access. To your first point, its how someone would say "we've never used it" when you buy a second hand item from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the previous owner rooted the thing or even flashed a custom ROM on it, but simply did a factory reset before handing it to you.

- Some custom ROMs are known to have USB debugging enabled by default.
- The existence of mobile data options might indicate that the custom ROM was built for or ported from a SIM-enabled variant of the device. However, it might also be a more pleasant surprise - it might support using certain 3G dongles via USB-OTG. That's the case for one of my past tablets.
- You are free to change between ART and Dalvik even on stock Android 4.4.x. Some OEMs do hide the option but it's unlikely your OEM is among one of them.

Ultimately I'll say if your device is running normally then just let it be.

Comment: Well, that helps. Any idea on what dongles **might** work?

Comment: @DanBrown Nope... Back when I owned that tablet (which has a Rockchip RK3066 SoC, popular for cheap tablets), similar tablets flood the market but none of them offered the same list of supported dongles. They do commonly support ones from ZTE and Huawei but still the exact models varied a bit. The only way to know for sure is to try acquiring info from the manufacturer.